# Htaccess não está redirecionando para página de erro 404

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho um `.htaccess` com a seguinte configuração:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /erro404.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC,L]
        RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Mas ele não está redirecionando quando eu digito uma página que não existe.
O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo sempre usar `RewriteBase`, isto evita alguns problemas, no caso se index.php estiver na pasta raiz:

```apacheconf
ErrorDocument 404 /erro404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(index|index/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Também pode-se usar PATH_INFO ao invés de GET para obter a rota:

```apacheconf
ErrorDocument 404 /erro404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(index|index/)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php/$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

No PHP ao invés de usar `$_GET['pagina']`, use:

```php
<?php
$path = empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? NULL : $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

var_dump($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente colocar esses comandos no topo do `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```